# Ignore non-numeric values in sumproduct formula in excel

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I tried to use sumproduct formula, but it doesn't ignore non numeric (text) values.

Tried double unary. But nothing works

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8="TX")*B2:B8)
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A8="TX")*B2:B8)
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8="TX")*--B2:B8)
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A8="TX")*--B2:B8)

State   Sales
UT  75
CO  100
TX  125
CO  125
TX  150
TX  a
CO  50
```

I know sumif can do, but im trying to achieve the same from Sumproduct, coz i need to apply it in larger frame

Comment: Why would you want to use a more sluggish slower function over `SUMIF`? Quite interested in why you would opt for `SUMPRODUCT` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8="TX")*(ISNUMBER(B2:B8)))`

To get the logical values.
If you want the result:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8="TX")*(ISNUMBER(B2:B8)),B2:B8)`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A8="TX"),B2:B8)
```

[image]

`SUMPRODUCT` function treats non-number value as zero.  So, you can directly use `B2:B8` as second argument without considering if it a text or number.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ISNUMBER** function which will ignore the non numeric value.

=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8="TX")*(ISNUMBER(B2:B8)),B2:B8)